# HRD with no unapplied jobs on GAE Java Dev Server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

For testing purposes I would need to run a local App Engine Java development server with the high-replication datastore (HRD), but with no unapplied jobs. I would like to have the same effect that I can get in my standalone unit tests with the following:

```
LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig cfg
    = new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig();
cfg.setApplyAllHighRepJobPolicy()
LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(cfg);
helper.setUp();
```

On the dev server those classes are not available, so is there any way to have a HRD with no unapplied jobs on the dev server?

(HRD is enabled for the dev app server with the JVM flag -`Ddatastore.default_high_rep_job_policy_unapplied_job_pct`. If I set it to zero, it will disable HRD and use the Master-Slave datastore instead)

I cannot simply use the Master-Slave datastore, as at least with objectify (4.0b) this creates trouble with cross-group transactions. They will fail with the following message: `cross-group transaction need to be explicitly specified`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your own job policy. This is what I use:

```
public class AlwaysApplyJobPolicy implements HighRepJobPolicy
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldApplyNewJob(Key arg0) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldRollForwardExistingJob(Key arg0) {
        // This should be irrelevant because all jobs apply immediately
        return true;
    }
}

private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
        new LocalServiceTestHelper(
                // Our tests assume strong consistency
                new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig().setAlternateHighRepJobPolicyClass(AlwaysApplyJobPolicy.class),
                new LocalMemcacheServiceTestConfig(),
                new LocalTaskQueueTestConfig());
```

Comment: That is basically what setApplyAllJobPolicy() does. However I cannot use that when running on the App Engine Java Development server, as LocalServiceTestHelper and related classes are not available there.